# Determine if a computer has a GPU during runtime in CUDA C

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

I'm writing code on a GPU enabled machine, but my code needs to be portable to computers without a GPU. So I wrote 2 functions, one that uses only the CPU and one that uses CPU+GPU.

I'm for a conditional compliance code, for example:

```
if (COMPUTER_HAS_GPU)
    //Run CPU+GPU code  
else  
    //Run CPU only code
```

Is there anything like this?

Comment: Your example suggests you don't want to do this at runtime, but at compile time. The easiest would be to add a define and let the user specify what they want.

Comment: You're right, my example did suggest runtime, but now I changed it to compile time.

Comment: @user10007692 I assume you meant your example suggested compile time, but you changed it to runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`cudaGetDeviceCount()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g665468e8cb33be42434f11bee2684ec9.html#g665468e8cb33be42434f11bee2684ec9)

For Example:

```
int devices = 0; 

cudaError_t err = cudaGetDeviceCount(&devices); 

if (devices > 0 && err == cudaSuccess) 
{ 
    // Run CPU+GPU code
} 
else
{ 
    // Run CPU only code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `cudaGetDeviceCount(*int);` function, that gives you how many cuda devices do you have and you can check the error code.

```
int i;

cudaError_t e = cudaGetDeviceCount(&i);

if (e == cudaErrorNoDevice) {
 // No CUDA device :-(
} else {
 // CUDA device .o/
}
```